# Reload collection view with new data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

How would I reload new data, say an array of names (strings), without re initializing the collection view with data?

I know of [uiCollectionView reloadData], but I wanted to changed the array of information associated with the collection view.

Comment: Change the data then call `reloadData` ?

Comment: I initialized with the data. How do I just change it?

Comment: Add items to the bound collections, or remove some?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reloadData` causes the collection view to ask its `dataSource` about what it now contains. Whatever the `dataSource` uses to decide, this is your collection view source data. If you change that data then you need to call `reloadData` for your UI to get updated. You can change the data however you want (like adding / removing items from the array or creating an entirely new array).

You never initialise the collection view with data. You initialise it with a `delegate` and `dataSource`. So you aren't re-initialising it. You're just changing the data that the `dataSource` is providing to the collection view.

Comment: So when you call initWithObjects, you arn't actually initializing with objects?

Comment: Well a better question is, how do I then go about changing the dataSource on the fly?

Comment: That isn't the collection view you're creating with `initWithObjects`. Why would you change the `dataSource` (I mean, you can just set a new one, but why)?

Comment: `UIPhotoCollectionViewController* uiPhotoCollectionViewController = [[UIPhotoCollectionViewController alloc] initWithData:[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:i]];`

dataArray is an array of arrays with strings in them. I need to change the data in the collection views.

Comment: So `UIPhotoCollectionViewController` is your collection view controller and the `dataSource` for the collection view. So give it a different array to use and reload when it gets a new array.

Comment: Yeah, i've been stuck on how to just give it a new array.

Comment: Just add a setter method.